# Issue finding lines using grep in UNIX

Tags: awk, grep, find, string

I am trying to use a .txt file with around 5000 patterns (spaced with a line) to search through another file of 18000 lines for any matches. So far I've tried every form of grep and awk I can find on the internet and it's still not working, so I am completely stumped.

Here's some text from each file.

Pattern.txt

```html
rs2622590
rs925489
rs2798334
rs6801957
rs6801957
rs13137008
rs3807989
rs10850409
rs2798269
rs549182
```

There's no extra spaces or anything.

File.txt

```html
snpid hg18chr bp a1 a2 zscore pval CEUmaf
rs3131972       1       742584  A       G       0.289   0.7726  .
rs3131969       1       744045  A       G       0.393   0.6946  .
rs3131967       1       744197  T       C       0.443   0.658   .
rs1048488       1       750775  T       C       -0.289  0.7726  .
rs12562034      1       758311  A       G       -1.552  0.1207  0.09167
rs4040617       1       769185  A       G       -0.414  0.6786  0.875
rs4970383       1       828418  A       C       0.214   0.8303  .
rs4475691       1       836671  T       C       -0.604  0.5461  .
rs1806509       1       843817  A       C       -0.262  0.7933  .
```

The file.txt was downloaded directly from a med directory.

I'm pretty new to UNIX so any help would be amazing!

This is copied from stackoverflow. I have tried every single thing that's been recommended but the output is still blank. Am I maybe missing a syntax issue or something in my text files?

P.S. Things I've tried:

```
grep -Fw -f Pattern.txt File.txt
fgrep -f Pattern.txt File.txt

FILENAME=$1
awk '{kount++;print   $0}' $FILENAME | fgrep -f - Pattern.txt

awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$0]; next} $2 in pats' Pattern.txt File.txt
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Crossposted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163970/how-to-find-lines-using-patterns-in-a-file-in-unix

Comment: @BananaMannock Why your output is blank? Because you don't have a same pattern inside `Pattern.txt` file from your `File.txt`. For testing, add `rs12562034` in your `Pattern.txt` file and try the commands given for you and you will luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -f Pattern.txt File.txt
```